# Checking if a record is saved in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am running a selenium script to add values to fields in a program , my goal is to find out in case the **SAVE** fails how to effectively log it ; such that I will know that the process of saving has failed and If there is an exception thrown ; which element/control it relates.

Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_toppanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_toppanelcontent']//div[@title='Add a new relation aa']")).Click();

```
        //add record
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]//input[@name='15986B36-838D-4F44-A7C7-04B2AFCA042F']")).SendKeys("MR");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]//input[@name='91D3E3C9-70C1-47B0-A125-FAAFBCA3C923']")).SendKeys("LOCAL ");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]//input[@name='963F62CE-0C57-435C-AEA8-CE912CA0BFFC']")).SendKeys("DUDE ");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]//input[@name='C360F8E7-D427-4067-A1E9-34C8644CCD2C']")).SendKeys("PLAIN");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath(" //div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]//input[@name='54EF9BEA-1AD3-4CCD-893C-291CEA82A561']")).SendKeys("SIMPLE");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[1]/tbody/tr[11]/td[3]//input[@name='3015E3A7-13BC-44FB-9844-A12B83F58D40']")).SendKeys("PLAIN@ymail.com");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Spliter1_RightP_Content']/table[@class='ob_spl_panel']/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanel']/div[@class='ob_spl_bottompanelcontent']/div/div[4]/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']//div[@class='row']/table[6]/tbody/tr[@class='H2Row']//table[@class='H2Table']//tr[@class='H2Row']/td[2]//input[@name='B3BF78C4-0833-466B-B8F3-85AFA812A4A2']")).SendKeys("jj@ymail.com");



        //Drop down
        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".row > .H2Table:nth-child(2) .H2Row:nth-of-type(1) .H2ComboBox span")).Click();
        //[ng-controller] .row > .H2Table:nth-child(2) .H2Row:nth-of-type(1) .chosen-single

        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-controller] .H2Row:nth-of-type(9) .H2ComboBox span")).Click();
        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-controller] .H2Row:nth-of-type(13) .H2ComboBox span")).Click();

        // calendar
        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-controller] .H2Table:nth-child(3) [src]")).SendKeys("GREGEG");
        Chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[ng-controller] .H2Table:nth-child(4) [src]")).Click();


        //save record

        Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='H2ReactMainToolStripContainer']//div[@title='Save']/img[@src='App_Themes/H2React/Icons/Actions-document-save-icon.png']")).Click();

        //pop up

        new WebDriverWait(Chrome, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//body[@class='ng-scope']/div[@role='dialog']//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[1]/span[@class='ui-button-text']"))).Click();
```

Comment: Added my code..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to confirm that saving a record has taken place successfully ?

Comment: That was a complicated way of asking the question (the code snippet doesn't help) but I have the same issue...  I'm running Selenium tests on an agGrid/Angular app, and would like to know how to test whether an "Add a new row" feature really did succeed in adding a row.